# Dynamic property name in API input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an ASP.NET Core API that takes in a DTO parameter called `DetParameterCreateDto` which looks like this

**DTO**

```
public class DetParameterCreateDto
{
    public int Project_Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Instrument { get; set; }
    public short Instrument_Complete { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the parameter passed in from the client has a property named `Instrument_Complete`; which is dynamic.

The name is actually `[instrument]_complete` where `[instrument]` is the name of the instrument. So if the name of the instrument is `my_first_project` then the parameter's property name will actually be `my_first_instrument_complete`, which will not properly map to my API's input parameter; so it always shows a value of 0

**API Method**

```
    [HttpPost("create")]
    public IActionResult CreateDetEntry(DetParameterCreateDto detParameters)
    {
       // some stuff in here
    }
```

**Update (8/2)**

Using bradley's suggestion it seems like I can do this with custom model binding. However, I have to set each model property instead of just the one I want to set `instrument_complete` (and convert some from string). This does not seem like an optimal solution.

```
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var instrumentValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("instrument").FirstValue;

        var model = new DetParameterCreateDto()
        {
            Project_Id = Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("project_id").FirstValue),
            Username = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("username").FirstValue,
            Instrument = instrumentValue,
            Instrument_Complete = Convert.ToInt16(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue($"{instrumentValue}_complete").FirstValue),

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }
```

Comment: You could probably use an `ActionFilter` to locate the parameter and alter its name before `CreateDetEntry` gets called.

Comment: Actually, a [custom `ModelBinder`](http://blog.learningtree.com/creating-a-custom-web-api-model-binder/) would probably be more appropriate for changing the way the data gets mapped.

Answer (score 1):

`DTO params` in Web API are limiting especially when the properties are dynamic. I solved a similar issue before by using `JObject`. Yours could be something like:

```
[HttpPost("create")]
public IActionResult CreateDetEntry(JObject detParameters)
{
    //DO something with detParameters
    ...
    //Optionally convert it to your DTO
    var data = detParameters.ToObject<DetParameterCreateDto>();
   // or use it as is
}
```

Comment: Will this still work if the data is not passed in JSON notation? I don't think that the API is using JSON because when I had `[FromBody]` in the params it didn't work. Also, Is it best practice to accept all parameters? I like having it strongly validated